# Getting error after deploy the new component

Tags: jss

I have created a new component to show Title, Description and Image. After deploying the component I am getting the following error:

> Minified React error #62; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=62&args[]= for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings

Please help me with this error. Also it will be great help if you can guide me how to start with Sitecore First Approach development.

Thanks,
Alok...

Comment: It would be useful if you share the code snippet. Are you using any inline styles in your component?

Comment: This error is occuring when I am using the Image field.
<Image
            field={props.fields.MediaImage}
            editable={false}
            imageParams={{ mw: 100, mh: 50 }}
            height="50"
            width="94"           
        />

Comment: I think your going to need to run the page with the non-minified React version to get a good error to post back in here.